# `Invoke-SqlCmd` does not display RAISERROR messages where `sqlcmd` does

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I switched from `sqlcmd` to `Invoke-SqlCmd`, and suddenly my RAISERROR messages disappeared. When I run it with `sqlcmd`, they appear. Is there any way to make them visible with `Invoke-SqlCmd`?

```sql
RAISERROR (N'Hello World',0,1) WITH NOWAIT;
```

```
Invoke-SqlCmd -Server $env:MSSQL_SERVERNAME -Username $env:MSSQL_USERNAME -Password $env:MSSQL_PASSWORD -Database "mydatabase" -Query "EXEC dbo.myprocedure" -OutputSqlErrors $true;
```

```
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S $env:MSSQL_SERVERNAME -U $env:MSSQL_USERNAME -P $env:MSSQL_PASSWORD -d mydatabase -Q "EXEC dbo.myprocedure";
```

Comment: What happens if you use `-verbose`?

Comment: @ScottHodgin, I thought I was the only one to post answers as comments ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation for [Invoke-Sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps), you can use `-verbose` to display the output messages.  From that post:

Example 5: Run a query and display verbose output

```
PS C:\> Set-Location "SQLSERVER:\SQL\MyComputer\MainInstance"
PS C:\> Invoke-SqlCmd -Query "PRINT N'abc'" -Verbose
VERBOSE: abc
```

I have bat file processes that use this technique and pipe the output of the messages to a file.  Example:

`-Verbose 4>&1> 'C:\AperioSync\SyncOutput.txt'"`

Comment: Thank you.  Is there any way to remove `VERBOSE:` prefix?